# AWS codecommit timeout in ubunutu virtual box

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, virtualbox, ubuntu-14.04, aws-codecommit

I am trying to work on a repo in an Ubuntu VM using virtual box.  I have everything from the aws codecommit set up tutorial configured correctly.  But when I run ssh -v git-codecommit.us-east-1.amazonaws.com. My connection times out.  It also times out if I try to clone a repository. I am using a network proxy to access the internet, so maybe my connection through that and virtual box is too slow.  Any thoughts on how to fix this?

Comment: Can you ssh out of the virtual box to a known host?

Comment: I will try sometime, but my network connection with my work computer at home is really slow so I don't know if it will work.